# Drag and Drop parecido com o da tela de atalho do android

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-n-drop

Estou utilizando Android 4.0 para desenvolver, preciso desenvolver um drag and drop no meu app e gostarei de fazer como da tela de atalhos, uma tabela 4x4 na tela. Com isso os elementos terão 16 lugares definidos e sempre que soltar um em cima do outro ele se reposiciona onde tiver lugar.

Agradeço desde já pela atenção!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topleft"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:background="#9864" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:src="@drawable/busca_crt" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myimage2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
public class draganddrop extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_draganddrop);
    findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage2).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage3).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
}

private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener{
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
             //   v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
               // v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                owner.removeView(view);
                LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
               // v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.draganddrop, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

tenho isso mais não sei se estou no caminho correto!

Comment: De mais detalhes do que você está tendo problemas, e poste o que você já fez. Assim é mais simples de entender o seu problema para poder lhe ajudar.

Comment: Acredito que nesse link você consegue resolver este problema. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: Acredito que [esta biblioteca](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie ) pode ajudar!